# Export result of a query to a text file by Teradata Parallel transporter

Tags: sql, powershell, csv, export, teradata

I need to automate an export of a large amount of data (from TERADATA by an sql query) to a pipe delimited text file. I used PowerShell (ConvertTo-CSV cmdlet) but it was very slow.
I was advised to use TPT to export but I have never used this Tool and all I have found is how to export one table to a flat file and not a complex query with more than a table.
Does someone know how to proceed with TPT or has a sample of a script for that?

**Edit :**

I am using this script for TPT but it has I think a lot of errors

```
DEFINE JOB EXPORT_DELIMITED_FILE
DESCRIPTION 'Export rows from a Teradata table to a delimited file'
(
DEFINE SCHEMA select EXPORT_DELIMITED_FILE from DELIMITED OF OPERATOR SQL_SELECTOR  
DEFINE OPERATOR SQL_SELECTOR
TYPE SELECTOR
SCHEMA *
ATTRIBUTES
(
VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'selector_log',
VARCHAR TdpId = 'Server',
VARCHAR UserName = 'user',
VARCHAR UserPassword = 'password',
VARCHAR SelectStmt = 'E:\PowerShell\SQL\file.sql',
VARCHAR ReportModeOn
);
DEFINE OPERATOR FILE_WRITER
TYPE DATACONNECTOR CONSUMER
SCHEMA *
ATTRIBUTES
(
VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'dataconnector_log',
VARCHAR DirectoryPath = 'E:\PowerShell\Output',
VARCHAR FileName = 'test_file.txt',
VARCHAR Format = 'Delimited',
VARCHAR OpenMode = 'Write',
VARCHAR TextDelimiter = '|'
);
APPLY TO OPERATOR (FILE_WRITER)

SELECT * FROM OPERATOR (SQL_SELECTOR);
);
```

Comment: You can provide a complex query as SelectStmt parameter of Export operator in TPT. Try executing the script and post any difficulties you experience with that.
Many examples and sample scripts can be found online. For example, see this [link](http://teradataexample.blogspot.com/2016/03/tpt-export-script-how-to-use-tpt-export.html)
Consult Teradata Parallel Transporter Quick Start Guide for general starter guides, Teradata Parallel Transporter Reference for complete reference.

Comment: I have made the script below and i have the following error, in fact i am not sure about what to put as to define the schema :                                                                                                           Syntax error: invalid token '' follows the syntax
"DEFINE SCHEMA ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema definition is wrong. Schema defines how your data set looks like in terms of field names and data types.

Producer operators (in your case SQL Selector) always need to have a defined schema. Deferred schema (`SCHEMA *`) can only be used with consumer operators (in your case Data Connector), which allows consumers to have the same schema as the related producer.

Schema definitions looks something like this:

```
DEFINE SCHEMA FILE_SCHEMA
(
    Column1 VARCHAR(255),
    Column2 VARCHAR(255),
    Column3 VARCHAR(255),
    Column4 VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Remember that data connector operator accepts only character data in the schema. If you specify any other data type, it will result in error.

Also, SelectStmt must contain an actual SQL query, not the path to file containing query. For exporting data to a flat file through data connector operator, you will need to cast everything to `VARCHAR` type in your query

```
SelectStmt = 'SELECT CAST(ColumnA AS VARCHAR(100), CAST(ColumnB AS VARCHAR(100), CAST(ColumnC AS VARCHAR(100), CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(100)) FROM MyTable GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;'
```

Note that number of columns returned by the SelectStmt are same as the define schema.

Also set `ReportModeOn = 'Y'` instead of leaving it to default value.

Always remember to indent the code. With indentation, the script now looks like:

```
DEFINE JOB EXPORT_DELIMITED_FILE
DESCRIPTION 'Export rows from a Teradata table to a delimited file'
(
    DEFINE SCHEMA FILE_SCHEMA
    (
        Column1 VARCHAR(100),
        Column2 VARCHAR(100),
        Column3 VARCHAR(100),
        Column4 VARCHAR(100)
    );

    DEFINE OPERATOR SQL_SELECTOR
    TYPE SELECTOR
    SCHEMA FILE_SCHEMA
    ATTRIBUTES
    (
        VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'selector_log',
        VARCHAR TdpId = 'Server',
        VARCHAR UserName = 'user',
        VARCHAR UserPassword = 'password',
        VARCHAR SelectStmt = 'SELECT CAST(ColumnA AS VARCHAR(100), CAST(ColumnB AS VARCHAR(100), CAST(ColumnC AS VARCHAR(100), CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(100)) FROM MyTable GROUP BY 1,2,3;',
        VARCHAR ReportModeOn = 'Y'
    );

    DEFINE OPERATOR FILE_WRITER
    TYPE DATACONNECTOR CONSUMER
    SCHEMA *
    ATTRIBUTES
    (
        VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'dataconnector_log',
        VARCHAR DirectoryPath = 'E:\PowerShell\Output',
        VARCHAR FileName = 'test_file.txt',
        VARCHAR Format = 'Delimited',
        VARCHAR OpenMode = 'Write',
        VARCHAR TextDelimiter = '|'
    );

    APPLY TO OPERATOR (FILE_WRITER)
    SELECT * FROM OPERATOR (SQL_SELECTOR);
);
```

Comment: thank you, still I have some errors left like this one : TPT_INFRA: Syntax error at or near line 399 of Job Script File 'space.tpt':
TPT_INFRA: TPT03046: Rule: DEFINE OPERATOR
Compilation failed due to errors. Execution Plan was not generated.
Job script compilation failed.

Comment: is there no way to put the path to sql ( cause it's a very big one 300 lines)

Comment: Sadly there is no direct way of putting the SQL in a file. One easy way to hide complexity would be to put the entire SQL in a database view and use `SELECT * FROM ViewName;` as SelectStmt. There aren't 399 rows in the shared script, I am assuming that the issue is due to the SELECT statement you are using. Make sure any single quotes in your query are properly escaped by an additional single quote to avoid incorrect close quote matching. But this won't be needed if you hide the logic in a database view.

Comment: Data connector uses only char/varchar types. You can use `TRIM ( TRAILING '.' FROM ColumnName)` to fix that.

Comment: Thank you it worked, an other question please, I saw that when using ReportModeOn = 'Y' , my types should be varchar. is there a way to use another type ? my data is mostly decimal(7,0) and when i cast it in the sql i have in output my numbers with a '.' in the end ( 123456. insted of 123456 for exemple). An other thing is that i used the trim function to take of the space that can be imported to the result ( trim(cast ( d.eanmax as varchar(20))) ) but the function doesn't appear to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TRIM` will remove spaces by default. You can nest trim statements like `TRIM (TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM (CAST (D.EANMAX AS VARCHAR (20))))`. Do accept the answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Thank you, Do you have an idea why trim is working for removing the point and not working for removing the space ?

Comment: You may use the attribute `TrimChar = ‘character’` with the DataConnector, which is by default a blank. Thus it should do the trimming. Except your space isn't a blank. It is a little odd, that TPT removes the trailing 0 but not the dot. You could `cast ( col as integer)`.  In ReportmodeON=Y  the type must be varchar, no other option.

Comment: If the select is embedded in the tpt script itself, it can span multiple lines. You don't have to squeeze it in one line. Thus you may not need an extra file. But still you have to be carefull with the quotes. having a view at hand is much easier.